# C# nullable check optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, nullable

Can anyone tell me how do I optimize below code.

```
if (report != null && 
    report.Breakdown != null &&
    report.Breakdown.ContainsKey(reportName.ToString()) &&
    report.Breakdown[reportName.ToString()].Result != null
    )
```

Comment: Optimise how? Performance? Shorter? Something else?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? C# 6's null conditional operator can help here.

Comment: Create an IsNull() operation on your Report type definition which does all the null checking for the report. Then you can just call it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, Yeah I want it to make shorter.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using c# 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use the `?.` operator to combine some of your null checks. However, if you're after optimizing for performance, you should avoid the double dictionary lookup (`ContainsKey` and index access), going for a `TryGetValue` instead:

```
MyType match = null;   // adjust type
if (report?.Breakdown?.TryGetValue(reportName.ToString(), out match) == true &&
    match?.Result != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Don't do "== true" ;-)

Comment: @Lucero: You need to in this case, since the result is `bool?`; otherwise, the compiler will give a syntax error.

Comment: @Douglas You could use the null coalescing operator `??`, either are fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use null conditional operator but only on C# 6

```
if ( report?.Breakdown?.ContainsKey(reportName.ToString()) == true &&
     report.Breakdown[reportName.ToString()].Result != null )
```

Comment: Gives compile time error as: Operator && can not be applied  to operands of type bool and bool?

Comment: sorry about that, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Ayman's answer is probably the best you can do for C# 6, for before that what you have there is pretty much the best you can do if all those objects are nullable.

The only way to optimize this further is to be checking if those objects are null before even calling the code, or better yet proofing your platform so this particular function shouldn't even be called in the first place if the values are null.

If you are just getting the value from from the dictionary however you can also simplify with the null coalescing operater '??'

Example:

```
MyDictionary['Key'] ?? "Default Value";
```

Thus if the Value at that entry is null you'll get the default instead.

So if this is just a fetch I'd just go

```
var foo = 
     report != null && 
     report.Breakdown != null &&
     report.Breakdown.ContainsKey(reportName.ToString()) ?
     report.Breakdown[reportName.ToString()].Result ?? "Default" :
     "Default";
```

But if you are actually doing things in the loop, then yeah you're pretty much at the best you can get there.

Answer (score 0):

For C# 6 and newer, you can do it this way:

```
if (report?.Breakdown?.ContainsKey(reportName.ToString()) == true &&
    report.Breakdown[reportName.ToString()].Result != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below? Also probably better to ship it to a method.

```
// unless report name is already a string
string reportNameString = reportName.ToString();
if ( report?.Breakdown?.ContainsKey(reportNameString) &&
     report.Breakdown[reportNameString].Result != null )
{
    // rest of the code
}
```